# Covered , Combined and Order of column in index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

I have 3 questions regarding index. If i have columns  `A B C D E F` in a table

#### Q1,  covered:

if i have :

```
index_A  =  A
index_AB  =  A+B
index_ABC  =  A+B+C
index_C  =  C
```

So if i just search  `A and/or B and/or C`. How does the db engine work:

- **always** go to `index_ABC` ?
- or if i just search  C , `index_C` will it be used, because it's smaller?

#### Q2, combine:

If i only have:

```
index_A  =  A
index_C  =  C
```

If i search for A+C will `index_A` and `index_C` help or do i need to build a  `index_AC`?

#### Q3 does order of columns matter?

Will searching `C` in  `index_CBA` be faster than `index_ABC`?

Comment: Read [**this link**](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) and try to understand how indexes work

Comment: Or if you want a whole series starting out basic and going fairly deep this is an excellent series on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/

Comment: I happen to think that the MySQL documentation does a good job of explaining how composite indexes are used for particular queries.  I would suggest that you start with:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.